# A grunt alternative - to compile sass and minify JS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, gruntjs

I'm after a linux server-side script I can run which can complete several tasks.

We currently have an in-house PHP framework - which runs on Apache with MySQL - the only server-side 'technology' we use is composer.

I am after a task runner - similar to grunt & gulp which does not run on Node and can work with an existing site set up - something that can be plugged in after the site is set up.

The thing that puts me off gulp and grunt is it suits your application if it is built on Node or you are using other node apps - otherwise you need a `package.js` along with a `Gruntfile`.

Tasks I would like it to run as a minimum is compiling Scss and minifying JS. Other tasks would be JS concatenation and image compression.

I've looked at Grunt, Gulp, Guard and Brunch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend just using Grunt, gulp, Brunch, etc as just a build tool. Meaning your PHP framework doesn't need to compile sass and minify js as the user requests the page. Use your build tool to produce the raw CSS and minified JS and just have your PHP framework serve those. Then Node.js is just a development dependency and not a production dependency.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i'm after. But if you _just_ using Grunt (with no other plugins or "apps") then there seems to be a lot of set up involved

Comment: Quite the opposite actually. Easy setup, compared to other build solutions, is one of the main reasons Node.js and it's build tools are so popular. Simply download/install from nodejs.org and `npm install`. Works on OSX, Linux and Windows with very little, if any at all, modification to the user's environment.

Comment: I don't know if your linux can run code kit, but it does all that and isn't node. Compass is too.

Comment: For anyone else following this up, I have, in the end, decided to go with gulp. Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 1):

`uglifyjs` will minify javascript, and other tools like `compass` can compile scss.

You can use `make` as a task runner to manage all that.

The default choice of Make, because of extremely widespread usage and software freedom, is to use [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), which has [a comprehensive manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: OOoh, interesting. Any recommended links on getting to grips with Make? Thats all i'm after really!

Comment: search for "makefile", there are plenty of tutorials available

Answer (score 0):

One of the very important and useful operation that you can do using **[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)** is running shell command, now it can be sequentially or in parallel.

Have a look at the [**grunt-shell**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell), using this you can run any sort of complex shell command.

You can run also **[bower](http://bower.io/)** to install all your dependencies directly into your assets so that you don't have to download them one by one.
There are whole lot of plugins available you can just look at them [here](http://gruntjs.com/plugins)